# Price Field Javascript and Jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have to validate a price textbox field with below conditions using javascript/jquery :

Please help me out to create a jquery for below validations :

- The 'Price' field will take in a negative value.
- 'Price' field should only display to the second decimal (and only allow a user to enter to the second decimal).
- 'Price' field should not be allowed to accept alphabetic characters.
- 'Price' field will accept multiple decimals. This value can be saved. (Multiple decimal is allowed,Regular Decimal not allowed after each decimal there can be only 2 digits).

Thanks a Ton.

Comment: how much will you pay me? :)

Comment: What do you mean by multiple decimals?

Comment: the price can be like  23.00.56.22.n so on

Comment: Why don't you just `Math.floor()` it?

Comment: That is not a valid number.

Comment: Yes but this is the requirement that i am having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use regular expression to validate the value of price

```
^-?(\d{1,3})(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

This regex will accept negative as well as positive values with numbers upto 1 to 999 and also with 2 decimal places

You modify the regex as per your requirement.

`\d{1,3}` - will accept upto 3 digits

`\.\d{1,2}` - will accept decimal digits upto 2 places

EDIT

This regex will allow 999.99.99.99 or 999.99.99 type values

```
^-?(\d{1,3})(\.\d{1,2})*?$
```

Explanation

```
(\.\d{1,2})* - This will accept dot multiple times
```

Comment: Partial working but not validating after one decimal(.).It should take 2 digits after each decimal.

Comment: Edited my answer. Try this ` ^-?(\d{1,3})(\.\d{1,2})*?$`

Comment: Thanks allot its working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this regular expression,

```
/^\d+(?:(\,||\.)\d\d?)*?$/

eg:

var newVal = $("#priceTextBox").val();
 var regexp = /^(0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)$/;

        if (regexp.test(newVal)) {
           alert("valid Price");

        }else{
               alert("Invalid");
        }
```

Comment: You should add a little JS code around this and maybe a couple of examples